# How can I get the file path where the file is in my project folder?

Tags: objective-c

I have a project on desktop and a file in this folder so this file is in the same folder as my .m .h files.
I want to get the path of this file. The `NSBundle` or `NSHomeDerictory` didn't give me the correct path. It seems the paths they gave is related to the simulator, not my working space.

Comment: In what context do you need this information? Compile time? Run time?

Comment: If you just want to include a file into the app bundle, you can just drag it into the xcode project. Any files not copied in this way will not be visible to your program at run time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is to use `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:resource ofType:type];` to get the path of the file.

For example, if I were to instantiate an NSMutableArray from the contents of a plist file, I would do something like:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"savedArray" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

You can do the same thing with resources of different types as well.