# Storing image information

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to develop an app which stores any user given data. But I would also like them to select an image/images from their photo library to "link" with their data. So when they select/view the specific sets of data in the app they can view the images as well. And I'm not sure what's the best way to go about doing this. I don't really want to create a copy of the image in my app ( don't know if it's done that way ) just being able to reference that specific image from the library is fine so long as the image remains in the library of course.

I'm aware that I'm able to select an image from the library with `UIImagePickerController` then get the selected image info in `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` but what I'm wondering is what information passed into `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` should I store locally in my so I know how to retrieve that image later when the target data is selected?

Do I store the image name then later make an image object from that image name? But what happens if there's ever ever a duplicate image name? Or am I over thinking it..

This is the code I have

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<UIImagePickerControllerInfoKey,id> *)info{
    UIImage *target = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [self.image setImage:target];

}
```

I can display the image..I just need to know what exactly to save to my app locally so I can reference that image from the library later.

Thank you!

Edit: I'm saving the image by doing this

```
NSURL* selectedimageurl = info[UIImagePickerControllerImageURL];
NSString* path = [selectedimageurl relativeString];
//Store path to be used later
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do that is to save only the image's name, you can use it later to search for it on the phone and get the path to display in your app.

You can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17915494/how-can-i-get-the-file-path-where-the-file-is-in-my-project-folder) to know to get a filePath in objective c.

Comment: Hi thank you for the response. How can I get the image name from didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo?